# SQL cumsum which resets

Tags: sql, cumsum

How can I implement a cumsum in SQL where the cumsum resets if it gets larger than a predfined value
Input

```
column: 10,20,20,15,100   val:25
Output:
        10,30,20,35,100
```

Answer (score 0):

The below sql query the sum function is used to calculate the cumsum i.e.., cumulative sum for the table which is ordered by using the column. From the below query the table is ordered by column which is mentioned as oredered column.

```
SELECT
    column,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(column) OVER (ORDER BY <ordering_column> ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) > val
        THEN column
        ELSE SUM(column) OVER (ORDER BY <ordering_column> ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    END AS cumsum
FROM
    table_name
ORDER BY
    <ord_column>;
```